# How to change default port number in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

How to change server socket port number in Dart Editor? Because local tomcat using the 8080. 
Seem this port changed from 3030 to 8080 after update to version 1.5.0.

```
    --- 9:41:37 AM Starting pub serve : podium ---
    Loading source assets... (0.6s)
    Loading di transformers... (2.2s)
    Loading angular transformers... (0.9s)
    Failed to create server socket (OS Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way    forbidden by its access permissions.
, errno = 10013), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
```

Comment: This error is also presented to me. It occurred after updating the SDK without updating the eclipse editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run pub serve manually `pub serve --port 1234` from command line and use a custom launch configuration with a defined URL that points to your pub serve.

dartbug.com is currently not available (at least for me) to verify if there is already a feature request, otherwise you should create one but I think I already saw one a while ago, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There was a feature request (for the predecessor of pub serve) but it was closed as 'NotPlanned' https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16654.
You should create a new feature request. Please add a link here when you do.

Comment: I also temporarily resolved with this answer. But there are solution make definitive on "eclipse launcher" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OSx platform and I had same error after updating only SDK folder, without updating any other tools, editor ect...

I solved temporarly with launching pub serv manually by terminal

```
pub serve --port 1234
```

But to solve problem on Eclipse Editor I must clean all files of Dart installation with "AppCleaner" and reinstall all with new installation. With this solution I solved the problem.